# Behavior of Path.toRealPath() in Java with more than one level of symbolic link

Tags: java, linux, file

what is the behavior of:

```
Path.toRealPath()
```

when there is more than one level of symbolic links? I am debugging a program remotely for a friend who is on Linux, and I suspect that he has more than one symbolic links levels.

I am currently doing:

```
Path path = Path.get(uri);
if (Files.isSymbolicLink(path)) {
   path = path.toRealPath();
   uri = path.toURI();
}
```

But maybe I should do something like that:

```
Path path = Path.get(uri);
while (Files.isSymbolicLink(path)) {
   path = path.toRealPath();
}
uri = path.toURI();
```

Comment: Is not this enough https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#toRealPath-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-

Comment: You are right, I did not see this in the API: "By default, symbolic links are resolved to their final target." Thanks!